# Trouble passing functions to other objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I am having trouble passing functions to other objects in Angular. Specifically, I have created a function `generateTile(coords)` that populates a tile that will then be given to leaflet. This function is in a MapComponent method. I think I understand why this is an issue as `this` refers to a different context. However I don't know how to work around this issue.

```
generateTile(coords) {
    ...
    return image;
}

private initMap(): void {
    this.map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5
    });

    L.TileLayer.CustomMap = L.TileLayer.extend({
        getTileUrl: function(coords) {
            var img = this.generateTile(coords);
            return img.src;
        },
        getAttribution: function() {
            return "<a href='https://example.com'>Example</a>"
        }
    });
...
}
```

Comment: maybe the question was not clear, but the issue is with this.generateTile(coords). My intention would be to have `this` of the MapComponent, however `this` in the anonymous function getTitleUrl is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function so you don't create a scope for `this`. You can read more about how `this` works in JavaScript, [here is a link](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8), for example.

```
  getTileUrl: (coords) => {
                var img = this.generateTile(coords);
                return img.src;
            };
```